# React-Native Account screen with a modal for updating details

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, react.js, jsx

Just looking for advice/thoughts on the overall AccountModal and how its written. looking to achieve better written, more legible, less repetitive code, more concise, cleaner etc...

AccountScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as Colors from '../assets/colors';
import * as Components from '../components';
import { onProfileChange } from '../actions/Profile';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

class AccountScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visible: false,
            modalType: null,
            modalData: ''
        };
        this.listener = props.onProfileChange(this.props.email);
    }
    setModal = (type) => {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible, modalType: type, modalData: this.props[type] });
    };
    renderConditionalOptions = () => {
        if (this.props.role === 'a') {
            return (
                <View>
                    {this.props.activated !== true ? (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={{
                                padding: width * 0.05,
                                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                            }}
                            onPress={() => this.setModal('activate')}
                        >
                            <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={'Activate/De-Activate'} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ) : null}
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.setModal('adultRated')}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={'Change Content Rating'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.setModal('categories')}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={'Modify Categories'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.verificationProcess}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={'Get Verified'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            );
        }
    };

    render () {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                {/* HEADER CONTAINER CONTAINER */}
                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    {/* IMG / NAME ROW */}
                    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => this.setModal('profileImg')}
                            style={{
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                borderColor: Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN,
                                borderWidth: 5,
                                borderRadius: width * 0.7,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE,
                                width: width * 0.35,
                                height: width * 0.35
                            }}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={{ borderRadius: width * 0.5, height: width * 0.33, width: width * 0.33 }}
                                source={
                                    this.props.profileImg != '' ? (
                                        { uri: this.props.profileImg }
                                    ) : (
                                        require('../assets/img/white-user.png')
                                    )
                                }
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={this.props.legalName}
                                style={{
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    marginTop: width * 0.01
                                }}
                            />
                            {/* Edit Username  */}
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => this.setModal('username')}
                                style={{
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE,
                                    borderRadius: width,
                                    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.025,
                                    paddingVertical: width * 0.015,
                                    marginTop: width * 0.01
                                }}
                            >
                                <Components.BodyText
                                    text={'@' + this.props.username}
                                    style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>

                {/* LOWER CONTAINER */}
                <View
                    style={{
                        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
                        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
                        borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
                        borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        width: width,
                        marginBottom: width * 0.05
                    }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.setModal('email')}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText text={'Update Email'} style={{ fontSize: 18 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.setModal('password')}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={'Change Password'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.setModal('phoneNumber')}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={'Update Phone Number'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    {/* CONDITIONAL OPTIONS */}
                    {this.renderConditionalOptions()}
                </View>

                {this.state.visible === true ? (
                    <Components.AccountModal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        data={this.state.modalData}
                        type={this.state.modalType}
                        closeModal={this.setModal}
                        navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    />
                ) : null}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        //justifyContent: 'space-between',
        backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
    },
    headerContainer: {
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
        width: width,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        shadowColor: '#333',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 3,
            height: 3
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 10,
        elevation: 15,
        paddingVertical: width * 0.05,
        marginBottom: 30
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = ({ profile }) => {
    const {
        role,
        activated,
        profileImg,
        legalName,
        username,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        bio,
        adultRated,
        categories,
        verified
    } = profile;

    return {
        role,
        activated,
        profileImg,
        legalName,
        username,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        bio,
        adultRated,
        categories,
        verified
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = { onProfileChange };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AccountScreen);
```

AccountModal.js:

```
//imports removed for brevity
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

class AccountModal extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rating: null,
            visible: props.visible,
            text: '',
            text2: '',
            showInput: false,
            type: '',
            img: '',
            categories: props.categories != null ? props.categories : []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        let first = this.props.type[0];
        this.setState({ type: this.props.type.replace(/^./, first.toUpperCase()) });
    }
    format = (input) => {
        let trimmed = input;
        trimmed = trimmed.includes(' ') ? trimmed.replace(' ', '-') : trimmed;
        return (trimmed = trimmed[0].toUpperCase() + trimmed.substring(1));
    };
    openImgPicker = () => {
        ImagePicker.openPicker({
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            cropping: true,
            cropperToolbarTitle: 'Pinch/Zoom to Crop Image',
            cropperCircleOverlay: true
        }).then((img) => {
            this.setState({ img: img.path });
        });
    };
    addCategory = () => {
        let trimmed = this.format(this.state.text);
        this.setState({ categories: [ ...this.state.categories, trimmed ] });
        this.refs.input.clear();
    };
    closeModal = () => {
        this.props.closeModal();
        this.refs.input.clear();
        this.props.resetInfo();
    };
    onSave = (type) => {
        switch (type) {
            case 'Bio':
                this.props.updateBio(this.props.docId, this.state.text);
                break;
            case 'Username':
                this.props.updateUsername(this.props.docId, this.state.text);
                break;
            case 'Email':
                this.props.updateEmail(this.props.docId, this.state.text);
                break;
            case 'Categories':
                this.props.updateCategories(this.props.docId, this.state.categories);
                break;
            case 'AdultRated':
                this.props.updateAdultRated(this.props.docId, this.state.rating);
                break;
            case 'ProfileImg':
                this.props.updateProfileImg({
                    uid: this.props.user.uid,
                    id: this.props.docId,
                    uri: this.state.img,
                    url: this.props.profileImg
                });
                break;
            case 'PhoneNumber':
                this.props.sendVerificationCode(this.state.text);
                this.refs.input.clear();
                break;
            case 'ConfirmCode':
                this.props.compareCode(
                    { id: this.props.verificationId, inputCode: this.state.text },
                    this.props.docId,
                    this.props.phoneNumber
                );
            case 'Verified':
            case 'Activate':
            case 'Deactivate':
        }
    };
    renderModal = () => {
        switch (this.state.type) {
            case 'Bio':
            case 'Username':
            case 'Email':
            case 'Verified':
                return (
                    <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        transparent={true}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={this.state.type + ':'}
                                style={{
                                    color: 'white',
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    marginBottom: 5
                                }}
                            />

                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={
                                    this.state.type === 'Selfie' ? (
                                        '$' + this.props.selfie + ' per selfie or screenshot'
                                    ) : this.state.type === 'Video' || this.state.type === 'Voice' ? (
                                        '$ ' + this.props[this.props.type] + ' per 5 minutes'
                                    ) : (
                                        this.props[this.props.type]
                                    )
                                }
                                style={{
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    marginBottom: 20,
                                    color: 'white',
                                    textAlign: 'center'
                                }}
                            />

                            <Components.TransparentInput
                                placeholder={'Edit...'}
                                placeholderColor={'white'}
                                style={{
                                    borderRadius: 20,
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    height: this.props.type === 'bio' ? width * 0.25 : width * 0.1,
                                    width: width * 0.6,
                                    marginBottom: 10,
                                    padding: 5
                                }}
                                ref={'input'}
                                multiline={this.props.type === 'bio' ? true : false}
                                onChangeText={(text) => {
                                    this.setState({ text: text.trim() });
                                }}
                            />

                            {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                <Components.BodyText text={this.props.info} fontSize={14} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
                            ) : null}

                            <ActivityIndicator
                                animating={this.props.loading}
                                color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                size={'small'}
                            />
                            // For specific firebase error forcing re-authentication
                            {this.props.info.includes('sensitive') ? (
                                <Components.Button
                                    text={'Re-Authenticate'}
                                    type={'alert'}
                                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}
                                />
                            ) : null}

                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: 10 }}>
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                                    type={'secondary'}
                                    text={'Close'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                />
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.onSave(this.state.type)}
                                    type={'primary'}
                                    text={'Save'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
            case 'ProfileImg':
                return (
                    <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        transparent={true}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={this.openImgPicker}
                                style={[ styles.transparentTouchable, { marginVertical: 20 } ]}
                            >
                                <Components.BodyText
                                    text={this.state.img != '' ? 'Image selected' : 'Tap to Select Image'}
                                    style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                <Components.BodyText text={this.props.info} fontSize={14} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
                            ) : null}

                            <ActivityIndicator
                                animating={this.props.loading}
                                color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                size={'small'}
                            />

                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: 10 }}>
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                                    type={'secondary'}
                                    text={'Close'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                />
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.onSave(this.state.type)}
                                    type={'primary'}
                                    text={'Save'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
            case 'AdultRated':
                return (
                    <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        transparent={true}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={
                                    this.state.rating == null ? (
                                        'Your current Adult Content rating: ' + '\n' + this.props.data
                                    ) : (
                                        "You're about to set Adult-Rated for: " + '\n' + this.state.rating
                                    )
                                }
                                style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}
                            />

                            <Components.Button
                                onPress={() => this.setState({ rating: true })}
                                type={'alert'}
                                text={'Set for Adults'}
                                fontSize={16}
                                style={{ margin: 15 }}
                            />

                            <Components.Button
                                onPress={() => this.setState({ rating: false })}
                                type={'alert'}
                                text={'Set for Everyone'}
                                fontSize={16}
                                style={{ margin: 15 }}
                            />

                            {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                <Components.BodyText text={this.props.info} fontSize={14} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
                            ) : null}

                            <ActivityIndicator
                                animating={this.props.loading}
                                color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                size={'small'}
                            />

                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: 15 }}>
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}
                                    type={'secondary'}
                                    text={'Close'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                />
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.onSave(this.state.type)}
                                    type={'primary'}
                                    text={'Save'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
            case 'Categories':
                return (
                    <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        transparent={true}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={this.state.type + ':'}
                                style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center' }}
                            />

                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={'Tap a category to delete'}
                                style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 12, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 20 }}
                            />

                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.categories}
                                style={{ marginVertical: 20 }}
                                horizontal={false}
                                numColumns={2}
                                keyExtractor={(item) => {
                                    return (
                                        item.toString() +
                                        new Date().getTime().toString() +
                                        Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime())).toString()
                                    );
                                }}
                                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            this.setState({
                                                categories: this.state.categories.filter((category) => {
                                                    if (item != category) {
                                                        return true;
                                                    } else {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                })
                                            });
                                        }}
                                        style={styles.transparentTouchable}
                                    >
                                        <Components.BodyText
                                            text={index + 1 + '. ' + item}
                                            style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'white' }}
                                        />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                )}
                            />

                            <View
                                style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                                    marginTop: 25,
                                    marginBottom: 15,
                                    alignItems: 'center'
                                }}
                            >
                                <Components.TransparentInput
                                    placeholder={'Add a category...'}
                                    placeholderColor={'white'}
                                    style={{ height: width * 0.1, width: width * 0.33, marginRight: 20 }}
                                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                                        this.setState({ text });
                                    }}
                                    returnKeyType={'done'}
                                    onSubmitEditing={() => this.addCategory()}
                                    ref={'input'}
                                />
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        this.addCategory();
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Image
                                        source={require('../assets/img/white-plus.png')}
                                        resizeMode={'contain'}
                                        style={{ height: width * 0.09, width: width * 0.09 }}
                                    />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>

                            {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                <Components.BodyText text={this.props.info} fontSize={14} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
                            ) : null}

                            <ActivityIndicator
                                animating={this.props.loading}
                                color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                size={'small'}
                            />

                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: 15 }}>
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                                    type={'secondary'}
                                    text={'Close'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                />
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.onSave(this.state.type)}
                                    type={'primary'}
                                    text={'Save'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
            case 'Activate':
                return (
                    <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        transparent={true}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={this.state.type + ' your account'}
                                style={{
                                    color: 'white',
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    marginBottom: 5
                                }}
                            />

                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={
                                    'Profile must be complete to activate account. Activation status determines whether profile is accessbile in the Discover section'
                                }
                                style={{
                                    color: 'white',
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    marginBottom: 5
                                }}
                            />

                            {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                <Components.BodyText text={this.props.info} fontSize={14} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
                            ) : null}

                            <ActivityIndicator
                                animating={this.props.loading}
                                color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                size={'small'}
                            />

                            <View
                                style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    marginBottom: 15
                                }}
                            >
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.onSave('Deactivate')}
                                    type={'action'}
                                    text={'De-Activate'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 20, height: width * 0.1 }}
                                />
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.onSave(this.state.type)}
                                    type={'primary'}
                                    text={'Activate'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                    style={{ height: width * 0.1 }}
                                />
                            </View>

                            <Components.Button
                                onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                                type={'secondary'}
                                text={'Close'}
                                fontSize={16}
                                style={{ height: width * 0.1 }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
            case 'Password':
                return (
                    <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        transparent={true}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={'Reset Password'}
                                style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18, textAlign: 'center' }}
                            />
                            {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                <Components.BodyText
                                    text={this.props.info}
                                    fontSize={14}
                                    style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', marginVertical: 20 }}
                                />
                            ) : null}

                            <ActivityIndicator
                                animating={this.props.loading}
                                color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                size={'small'}
                            />

                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: 10 }}>
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                                    type={'secondary'}
                                    text={'Close'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                />
                                <Components.Button
                                    onPress={() => this.props.sendPwdLink(this.props.email)}
                                    type={'primary'}
                                    text={'Reset'}
                                    fontSize={16}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
            case 'PhoneNumber':
                return (
                    <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        transparent={true}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={'Update Phone Number'}
                                style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 }}
                            />
                            {this.props.verificationId == null ? (
                                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Components.TransparentInput
                                        placeholder={'Enter new phone number'}
                                        placeholderColor={'white'}
                                        style={{
                                            height: width * 0.1,
                                            width: width * 0.45,
                                            marginTop: 20,
                                            marginBottom: 5
                                        }}
                                        onChangeText={(text) => {
                                            this.setState({ text: text.trim() });
                                        }}
                                        returnKeyType={'done'}
                                        ref={'input'}
                                    />
                                    <Components.BodyText
                                        text={
                                            "Remember to include a '+', your country code, followed by your number. No spaces or hyphens."
                                        }
                                        style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
                                    />
                                    {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                        <Components.BodyText
                                            text={this.props.info}
                                            fontSize={14}
                                            style={{ marginTop: 25, color: 'white' }}
                                        />
                                    ) : null}

                                    <ActivityIndicator
                                        animating={this.props.loading}
                                        color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                        size={'small'}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: 15 }}
                                    >
                                        <Components.Button
                                            onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                                            type={'secondary'}
                                            text={'Close'}
                                            fontSize={16}
                                            style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                        />
                                        <Components.Button
                                            onPress={() => {
                                                this.onSave(this.state.type);
                                            }}
                                            type={'primary'}
                                            text={'Send Code'}
                                            fontSize={16}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            ) : (
                                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Components.TransparentInput
                                        placeholder={'Enter confirmation code'}
                                        placeholderColor={'white'}
                                        style={{ height: width * 0.1, width: width * 0.45 }}
                                        onChangeText={(text) => {
                                            this.setState({ text: text.trim() });
                                        }}
                                        returnKeyType={'done'}
                                        ref={'input'}
                                    />

                                    {this.props.info != '' ? (
                                        <Components.BodyText
                                            text={this.props.info}
                                            fontSize={14}
                                            style={{ color: 'white' }}
                                        />
                                    ) : null}

                                    <ActivityIndicator
                                        animating={this.props.loading}
                                        color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN}
                                        size={'small'}
                                    />

                                    <View
                                        style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: 15 }}
                                    >
                                        <Components.Button
                                            onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                                            type={'secondary'}
                                            text={'Close'}
                                            fontSize={16}
                                            style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                        />
                                        <Components.Button
                                            onPress={() => this.onSave('ConfirmCode')}
                                            type={'primary'}
                                            text={'Confirm Code'}
                                            fontSize={16}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            )}
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
        }
    };

    render () {
        return <View>{this.renderModal()}</View>;
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalContainer: {
        width: width * 0.8,
        backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY_DARK,
        borderRadius: 20,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN,
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        shadowColor: '#333',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 30,
            height: 30
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.9,
        shadowRadius: 30,
        elevation: 15,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: height * 0.25,
        paddingTop: 15,
        paddingBottom: 25
    },
    transparentTouchable: {
        margin: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE,
        borderRadius: width,
        paddingHorizontal: width * 0.025,
        paddingVertical: width * 0.015
    }
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    updateBio,
    resetInfo,
    updateUsername,
    updateEmail,
    updateCategories,
    updateAdultRated,
    updateProfileImg,
    updatePassword,
    sendPwdLink,
    sendVerificationCode,
    compareCode
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ profile, auth }) => {
    const {
        activated,
        profileImg,
        legalName,
        username,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        bio,
        adultRated,
        categories,
        verified,
        info,
        loading,
        docId,
        selfie,
        video,
        voice,
        verificationId
    } = profile;
    const { user, error } = auth;
    return {
        activated,
        profileImg,
        legalName,
        username,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        bio,
        adultRated,
        categories,
        verified,
        info,
        user,
        loading,
        docId,
        selfie,
        video,
        voice,
        error,
        verificationId
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AccountModal);
```

Answer (score 2):

- We can create a method to dynamically serve the redundant `TouchableOpacity` block as below:

  ```js
  <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
          padding: width * 0.05,
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
      }}
      onPress={() => this.setModal(setModal)}
  >
      <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={textContent} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
  ```
- Destructuring the `state` and `props` using ES6 destructuring.

  ```
  const {visible, modalData, modalType} = this.state;
  const {navigation} = this.props;
  ```
- To keep `main` render clean we can further extract the `IMG`, `ROW` JSX into a method `__renderImgNameRow`

Applying all this yields:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as Colors from '../assets/colors';
import * as Components from '../components';
import { onProfileChange } from '../actions/Profile';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

class AccountScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visible: false,
            modalType: null,
            modalData: ''
        };
        this.listener = props.onProfileChange(this.props.email);
    }
    setModal = (type) => {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible, modalType: type, modalData: this.props[type] });
    };
    renderConditionalOptions = () => {
        if (this.props.role === 'a') {
            return (
                <View>
                    {this.props.activated !== true ? (
                        this.__renderLowerTouchables('activate', 'Activate/De-Activate')
                    ) : null}
                    {this.__renderLowerTouchables('adultRated', 'Change Content Rating')}
                    {this.__renderLowerTouchables('categories', 'Modify Categories')}

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.verificationProcess}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={'Get Verified'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            );
        }
    };

    __renderLowerTouchables = (setModal, textContent) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            padding: width * 0.05,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
                        }}
                        onPress={() => this.setModal(setModal)}
                    >
                        <Components.BodyText style={{ fontSize: 18 }} text={textContent} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

    __renderImgNameRow = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => this.setModal('profileImg')}
                            style={{
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                borderColor: Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN,
                                borderWidth: 5,
                                borderRadius: width * 0.7,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE,
                                width: width * 0.35,
                                height: width * 0.35
                            }}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={{ borderRadius: width * 0.5, height: width * 0.33, width: width * 0.33 }}
                                source={
                                    this.props.profileImg != '' ? (
                                        { uri: this.props.profileImg }
                                    ) : (
                                        require('../assets/img/white-user.png')
                                    )
                                }
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Components.BodyText
                                text={this.props.legalName}
                                style={{
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    marginTop: width * 0.01
                                }}
                            />
                            {/* Edit Username  */}
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => this.setModal('username')}
                                style={{
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE,
                                    borderRadius: width,
                                    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.025,
                                    paddingVertical: width * 0.015,
                                    marginTop: width * 0.01
                                }}
                            >
                                <Components.BodyText
                                    text={'@' + this.props.username}
                                    style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
        )
    }

    render () {
        const {visible, modalData, modalType} = this.state;
        const {navigation} = this.props;
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                {/* HEADER CONTAINER CONTAINER */}
                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    {/* IMG / NAME ROW */}
                    {__renderImgNameRow()}
                </View>
                {/* LOWER CONTAINER */}
                <View
                    style={style.lowerContainer}
                >
                    {this.__renderLowerTouchables('email', 'Update Email')}
                    {this.__renderLowerTouchables('password', 'Change Password')}
                    {this.__renderLowerTouchables('phoneNumber', 'Update Phone Number')}
                    {/* CONDITIONAL OPTIONS */}
                    {this.renderConditionalOptions()}
                </View>

                {visible && (
                    <Components.AccountModal
                        visible={visible}
                        data={modalData}
                        type={modalType}
                        closeModal={this.setModal}
                        navigation={navigation}
                    />
                )}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        //justifyContent: 'space-between',
        backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY_OFF_WHITE
    },
    headerContainer: {
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
        width: width,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        shadowColor: '#333',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 3,
            height: 3
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 10,
        elevation: 15,
        paddingVertical: width * 0.05,
        marginBottom: 30
    },
    lowerContainer: {
                        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
                        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
                        borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
                        borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        width: width,
                        marginBottom: width * 0.05
                    }
});

const mapStateToProps = ({ profile }) => {
    const {
        role,
        activated,
        profileImg,
        legalName,
        username,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        bio,
        adultRated,
        categories,
        verified
    } = profile;

    return {
        role,
        activated,
        profileImg,
        legalName,
        username,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        bio,
        adultRated,
        categories,
        verified
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = { onProfileChange };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AccountScreen);
```